# Which elements of a block are hashed?

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory, block

Other than the previous block hash and nonce data, which elements of a block are concatenated in order to be hashed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole block header is hashed including:

1. Block version number
2. 256-bit hash of the previous block header
3. 256-bit hash based on all of the transactions in the block (hashMerkleRoot)
4. the current timestamp as seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00 UTC
5. Bits (updated when he difficulty is adjusted)
6. Nonce

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm